# sorting array using two keys, If two values of a key is same then use another key?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a php array in which there are two keys i have to consider while sorting, if count of two users is same then consider another key for those values.

Ex. [image: Table structure for example]

```
$result = $client->getTopUsers();
for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
{

    if($result[$i]['count'] == $result[$i + 1]['count'])
    {
        if($result[$i + 1]['liked'] > $result[$i]['liked'])
        {
            $result[$i + 1]['rank'] = $i-2;
            $result[$i]['rank'] = $i + 1;
        } else
        {
            $result[$i]['rank'] = $i;
        }
    } else
    {
        $result[$i]['rank'] = $i;
    }
    $result[$i]['rank'];
}
```

In above picture, count of last 2 entries is same so i want my rank to be according liked_count.This is what i have tried so far but i am not getting the result("RANK") as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ORDER BY** in your query, no need to sort the data in PHP code, See below example

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u 
ORDER BY u.count DESC, u.liked_count DESC
```

Its giving me something like this, [image: Result]

Comment: Please check the edit, I want liked_count to be in order as well.

Comment: @RayonDabre Do you wand likedcount ASC or DESC?

Comment: The person who have got more likes will be on heigher side.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can solve your problem

```
select rownum as rnk,field_1,field_2 from (select * from table_name order by key_field1,key_field2 desc limit 10) order by rownum ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from veer_user_details 
order by count desc, liked_count desc;
```

This query worked for me.